# MYSQL,PHP,MEMCACHED - Display recent 20 posts along with recent four comments

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I am analyzing different approaches to display the recent 20 posts along with latest 4 comments for each post . This is some what like facebook wall , but won't have likes,share and any other

#### Example Table Structure

posts

- `p_id` = the number of that post
- `user_id` = user they are posting about
- `poster_user_id` = the person making the post
- `post`

comments

- `comment_id` = the number of that comment
- `post_id` = the number of the post the comment is related to
- `commenter_user_id` = the person who is making that comment
- `comment`

The approaches comes to my mind

**1)** Query POST table and get the recent 20 posts , send the post ID's to the database and get the comments from COMMENT table. But for this total calls will be

*1(posts)+20(comments)=21 DB calls*

**2)**  Join POST and COMMENT table and get all the comments for the recent 20 posts and when displaying check for the previous POST_ID and if it is same do not display the post , but only the comment . But this approach

*gets lot of unnecessary data*

**3)** Query POST table and get the recent 20 posts,get post IDs, construct comments query dynamically (in PHP that creates below kind of query)

```
 SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE post_id=<1st latest_id> ORDER BY comment_id desc LIMIT 4
UNION ALL
 SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE post_id=<2nd latest_id> ORDER BY comment_id desc LIMIT 4
UNION ALL
 SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE post_id=<3rd latest_id> ORDER BY comment_id desc LIMIT 4
....................up to 20
```

Here you will have only

*1(posts)+1(comment ) = two database calls*

This approach looks OK

**4)** Use the third approach and store the result in memcached for one minute or in 30 seconds . In case user makes any comment or new post,  use jquery and update his entry in the browser . In case if he presses refresh send a flag to the server to query the database again and store them in memcached .

*This approach only requires 1 or 2 database calls in a minute, but again user gets the data that was posted one minute ago , not recent one .. this is fine for regular forums*

**5)** Even instead of querying database for every minute , very first time get the top 20 posts from database and keep them in memcached along with comments  . Whenever user writes a new post , remove the 20th post from memcached and add the new post as 1st top post . Also for comments remove the 4th comment and attach the new comment to the post . But this requires a development work . Of course we have to save the record to database ( or can follow some group commit in case required) .

*This looks like best approach for me , if we code perfectly*

Any one has any other approaches or any good links to implement 5th approach ? ( updating memcached )

Thanks all for your help

Comment: You don't need 21 database calls, you need 2, total and memcache those. make a `hash` of the SQL and that can be your unique key.  When something is updated, you can force a reset on those keys. KEEP A CONVENTION.  It will allow you to not write unecessary code later.

Comment: Thanks bigman for your comment .yes for updating I can query the database again , but the 5th approach what I was talking is not even calling the database even if there are any database changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [user variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) trickery:

```sql
SELECT   post_id, comment_id
FROM     (
  SELECT   post_id, comment_id,
           @i := IF(@type <=> post_id, @i+1, 0) AS comment_number,
           @p := post_id
  FROM     comments NATURAL JOIN (SELECT * FROM (
             SELECT p_id AS post_id FROM posts ORDER BY p_id DESC LIMIT 20
           ) z) z, (SELECT @type:=NULL) init
  ORDER BY post_id DESC, comment_id DESC
) t
WHERE    comment_number < 4
ORDER BY post_id DESC, comment_id DESC
```

This still requires that a temporary table `t` be populated from all of those posts' comments, then filtered (in the outermost query) for only the top 4.  One could avoid this with a suitably ordered compound index on `(post_id, comment_id)`:

```sql
SELECT   post_id, comment_id,
         @i := IF(@type <=> post_id, @i+1, 0) AS comment_number,
         @p := post_id
FROM     comments FORCE INDEX (index_name) NATURAL JOIN (SELECT * FROM (
           SELECT   DISTINCT post_id
           FROM     comments
           ORDER BY post_id DESC
           LIMIT    20
         ) z) z, (SELECT @type:=NULL) init
GROUP BY post_id DESC, comment_id DESC
HAVING   comment_number < 4
```

Comment: +1, that's pretty impressive use of SQL, adding to favorites.

Comment: @eggyal I know this is a complex solution, but what kind of performance kick do you think this will have?  For what he is trying to do, you could run a few queries on an update to a post to re-cache exactly what he wants and likely cost the same as what you're doing above.  Thoughts?

Comment: @bigman: Exact performance comparison is impossible without vastly more information over specifics (down to hardware configuration, server settings, etc).  Best to benchmark and find out.

Comment: I realize an exact performance comparison is impossible, just asking for your thoughts on what would be more practical ;)  "Personally", I would setup a php daemon (overkill, yes but I like them) to poll the database and run an update script.  Would be pretty seamless and quick.

Comment: @eggyal :- I think creating compound primary key on ( post_id, comment_id ) supports descending order index . Your comment please on this ..

Comment: @eggyal :-  Thank You , I am confused with this article  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/09/descending-indexing-and-loose-index-scan/

Comment: @eggyal: Thanks again for clarifying . Answers most of my questions.